# plotting a vector field over a triangular mesh

Tags: matlab

I have a triangulation of the unit square and the x- and y-components of a vector field for each node of this triangulation.

What I'd like to do is plot the vector field over the triangular mesh, but so far I've been unable to find a way to do this. Matlab's quiver-command requires a meshgrid, which I don't have.

Is there a way to plot something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB's [`quiver`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) does not require a `meshgrid` input. You can specify any arbitrary `x`,`y`, `u`, and `v` as long as they are the same size:

```
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
q = quiver(t, sin(t), sin(t), sin(t));
```

[image]

The only time that it requires a `meshgrid` input is if you don't want to fully specify `x` and `y`:

```
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(1:10, 1:10);

%// Notice that for x and y we only provide vectors while xx/yy are matrices
q = quiver(1:10, 1:10, xx, yy);
```

[image]